# Which is the most linked question?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious to know which question is the most linked question, but there seems to be no similar queries that can search about it.

Which question is the most linked by other questions?

Comment: It's obviously going to be *that* regex question...

Comment: @MacroMan Do you mean the one where the top rated answer has a long rant about parsing and completely missed the fact that the question was about lexing rather than parsing?

Comment: @kasperd And this whole time I thought it was a rant about ponies...

Comment: Wait, that was a rant!? I've been degaussing my CRT monitor for months!!!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can determine this yourself, using a variation on [the technique used to count duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-is-the-most-rampant-duplicate-on-stack-exchange-sites/168289#168289):

```
select top 30 count(*) as links, 
 concat('https://stackoverflow.com/q/', RelatedPostId) as Q

from PostLinks

where LinkTypeId=1

group by RelatedPostId
order by count(*) desc
```

Which'll produce something like this:

- x7011 [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)
- x5859 [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)
- x5789 [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)
- x3414 [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942)
- x3225 [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142)
- x3030 [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242)
- x2991 [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384)
- x2990 [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)
- x2437 [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832)
- x2111 [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845)
- x1745 [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816)
- x1483 [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957)
- x1468 [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202)
- x1440 [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)
- x1404 [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133)
- x1290 [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982)
- x1218 [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486)
- x1097 [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636)
- x1045 [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198)
- x1015 [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)
- x994 [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480)
- x940 [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)
- x935 [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722)
- x917 [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115)
- x893 [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166)
- x876 [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733)
- x843 [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251)
- x832 [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021)
- x815 [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102)
- x766 [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226)

Note that this is counting *all* questions that linked to the target, even deleted ones. Adjusting this query to only count visible questions is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: [Ḩ̺̞̠̬̠̺ͨͥ͋ͩ͊͞ȩ̶͓̭̠͕̯̠̯̎̒̈̑́̈̌̈ ̷̺̰̻̼̮̲̗̺ͪ͋͛͋ͤ̒͐c̟̦ͭ̏̿̓͆̚ó̧͉͖͙̙͕͓̣͔̉ͫͤm̶̻̟̬̭̙͐̐͢e̸̺̟̜͕̊̏͑ͩͪ͐̎́̀͟s̢̡̖̤͓̘̣̬̟ͤ.̱̥̲͉̼̩͇̃̒ͦͬ̀̀͢.̻̠̩̞̜̦̟̱̈́̄̋̄̒.̡̰̦͎͕̮̓̆ͧ͞](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/621962)

Comment: "You can determine this yourself" It's not clear exactly what one is supposed to do with the SQL fragment in question. I assume this should be used on SEDE? Could we perhaps have a link to run the query?

Comment: Here you go, @karl https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1613574/top-30-most-linked-questions

Comment: Why are the reported counts much higher than what I see on the web site when I check out the individual questions? Is there more to it than just deleted questions/links?

Comment: Deleted is a good possibility there, @Karl - the top two in particular are frequent targets for links from questions that are unlikely to survive long unless the author reads and understands the linked question.