# Visualizing duplicate chain and changing duplicate target

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Is there a way to see what questions have been linked as duplicates to a question?

There is a link on the question marked as a duplicate that shows `duplicate -> original` link.  Is there a way to see `original -> duplicate(s)`

My motivation behind wanting to see this information is this question

[how to transfer a file through SFTP in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830146/how-to-transfer-a-file-through-sftp-in-java)

Which was closed as a duplicate of this question

[Transfer files via SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094938/transfer-files-via-sftp)

However, the dup target has a single link-only answer and is not a good dup target IMO.  Based off voting and views, the duplicate is a far better target for any of these types of questions.

**EDIT**:

It looks like the link-only answer on the target question has now been deleted, but it's still linked as the dup target.  So the duplicate question is closed as a duplicate of a question that now has no answers.

**EDIT in response to duplicate close votes**:

The query from the linked answer is a good starting point, but doesn't actually provide the requested info.  It finds the *most linked* answers for all of stack overflow, not a list of questions tagged as duplicates for a specific question.

This question is also a two-part question, relating to a specific question that may require moderator attention.

Comment: IIRC we have a dupe for this question, answered with an appropriate SEDE query.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310862/which-is-the-most-linked-question

Comment: @rene Yeah, that looks quite appropriate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Please see edits in response to linked answer.  Thanks

Comment: I agree reference should be held both forward and backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508299/linked-duplicates?QuestionID=8094938) that will show all the questions that have been linked as duplicates of a specific question.

```
select PostID as [Post Link]
from PostLinks
where LinkTypeId=3 and RelatedPostId = ##QuestionID:int##
```